# rake test:profile gives errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am trying to do some tests on my app. Based on this guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html)

I run commands like this **rake test:profile** and **rake test:benchmark**

Both times it gives me such errors :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions.rescue_responses is deprecated. Please configure your exceptio application config instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/darbs/config/environment.
/home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/darbs/app/models/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Admin is not a class (TypeError)
```

**Admin.rb**

```
    class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
       devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable   
       attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me  
    end
```

Somebody has ideas that may help me ? Thanks

Comment: Show your `admin.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
```

line as the first line in your `admin.rb` file. But you probably have constant named `Admin` defined somewhere else in your app. Change name of this constant.

Comment: I am using Active admin gem, where is some part of Admin used. That is the problem ?

Comment: Unlikely. I'd try to find `Admin` definition in your initializer.

Comment: There I could just find ActiveAdmin file, but not just admin.

Comment: It's not about file, it's about constant definition. Something like `Admin = 'something'` in your source code.

Comment: I searched all over Initializer folder, and did not find any admin constant. There is other way to locate this constant in my project ?